# Is there a difference between foreach and map?

Tags: foreach, language-agnostic, computer-science, map-function

Ok this is more of a computer science question, than a question based on a particular language, but is there a difference between a map operation and a foreach operation? Or are they simply different names for the same thing?

Comment: Curiously, if I get an `Iterator[String]` from `scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/me/file").getLines()` and apply `.foreach(s => ptintln(s))` to it, it is printed ok but gets empty right after. At the same time if I apply `.map(ptintln(_))` to it - it just gets empty and nothing is printed.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Different.

foreach iterates over a list and **performs** some operation with side effects to each list member (such as saving each one to the database for example)

map iterates over a list, **creates a transformed element** for each member of that list, and returns another list of the same size with the transformed elements (such as converting a list of strings to uppercase)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something along these lines but wasn't sure!

Comment: but you could have side-effects happen in the map function too.I like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4927981/375688

Comment: One important point to mention (this is particularly true in Scala) is that a call to `map` does **not** result in the execution of its underlying logic until when the expected transformed list is summoned. In contrast, `foreach`'s operation is computed immediately.

Answer (score 142):

The important difference between them is that `map` accumulates all of the results into a collection, whereas `foreach` returns nothing. `map` is usually used when you want to transform a collection of elements with a function, whereas `foreach` simply executes an action for each element.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand the difference. It had been hazy for me for quite some time

Answer (score 40):

In short, `foreach` is for applying an operation on each element of a collection of elements, whereas `map` is for transforming one collection into another.

There are two significant differences between `foreach` and `map`.

1. `foreach` has no conceptual restrictions on the operation it applies, other than perhaps accept an element as argument. That is, the operation may do nothing, may have a side-effect, may return a value or may not return a value. All `foreach` cares about is to iterate over a collection of elements, and apply the operation on each element.

   `map`, on the other hand, does have a restriction on the operation: it expects the operation to return an element, and probably also accept an element as argument. The `map` operation iterates over a collection of elements, applying the operation on each element, and finally storing the result of each invocation of the operation into another collection. In other words, the `map` *transforms* one collection into another.
2. `foreach` works with a single collection of elements. This is the input collection.

   `map` works with two collections of elements: the input collection and the output collection.

It is not a mistake to relate the two algorithms: in fact, you may view the two hierarchically, where `map` is a specialization of `foreach`. That is, you could use `foreach` and have the operation transform its argument and insert it into another collection. So, the `foreach` algorithm is an abstraction, a generalization, of the `map` algorithm. In fact, because `foreach` has no restriction on its operation we can safely say that `foreach` is the simplest looping mechanism out there, and it can do anything a loop can do. `map`, as well as other more specialized algorithms, is there for expressiveness: if you wish to map (or transform) one collection into another, your intention is clearer if you use `map` than if you use `foreach`.

We can extend this discussion further, and consider the `copy` algorithm: a loop which clones a collection. This algorithm too is a specialization of the `foreach` algorithm. You could define an operation that, given an element, will insert that same element into another collection. If you use `foreach` with that operation you in effect performed the `copy` algorithm, albeit with reduced clarity, expressiveness or explicitness. Let's take it even further: We can say that `map` is a specialization of `copy`, itself a specialization of `foreach`. `map` may *change* any of the elements it iterates over. If `map` doesn't change any of the elements then it merely *copied* the elements, and using *copy* would express the intent more clearly.

The `foreach` algorithm itself may or may not have a return value, depending on the language. In C++, for example, `foreach` returns the operation it originally received. The idea is that the operation might have a state, and you may want that operation back to inspect how it evolved over the elements. `map`, too, may or may not return a value. In C++ `transform` (the equivalent for `map` here) happens to return an iterator to the end of the output container (collection). In Ruby, the return value of `map` is the output sequence (collection). So, the return value of the algorithms is really an implementation detail; their effect may or may not be what they return.

Comment: For an example of how `.forEach()` can be used to implement `.map()`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39159854/1524693

Answer (score 34):

### `Array.protototype.map` method & `Array.protototype.forEach` are both quite similar.

Run the following code: http://labs.codecademy.com/bw1/6#:workspace

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.map(function(val, ind, arr){
    console.log("arr[" + ind + "]: " + Math.pow(val,2));
});

console.log();

arr.forEach(function(val, ind, arr){
    console.log("arr[" + ind + "]: " + Math.pow(val,2));
});
```

**They give the exact ditto result.**

```
arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 4
arr[2]: 9
arr[3]: 16
arr[4]: 25

arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 4
arr[2]: 9
arr[3]: 16
arr[4]: 25
```

### But the twist comes when you run the following code:-

*Here I've simply assigned the result of the return value from the map and forEach methods.*

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var ar1 = arr.map(function(val, ind, arr){
    console.log("arr[" + ind + "]: " + Math.pow(val,2));
    return val;
});

console.log();
console.log(ar1);
console.log();

var ar2 = arr.forEach(function(val, ind, arr){
    console.log("arr[" + ind + "]: " + Math.pow(val,2));
    return val;
});

console.log();
console.log(ar2);
console.log();
```

**Now the result is something tricky!**

```
arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 4
arr[2]: 9
arr[3]: 16
arr[4]: 25

[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 4
arr[2]: 9
arr[3]: 16
arr[4]: 25

undefined
```

## Conclusion

`Array.prototype.map` returns an array but `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't. So you can manipulate the returned array inside the callback function passed to the map method and then return it.

`Array.prototype.forEach` only walks through the given array so you can do your stuff while walking the array.

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer:** `map` and `forEach` are different. Also, informally speaking, `map` is a strict superset of `forEach`.

**Long answer:** First, let's come up with one line descriptions of `forEach` and `map`:

- `forEach` iterates over all elements, calling the supplied function on each.
- `map` iterates over all elements, calling the supplied function on each, and produces a transformed array by remembering the result of each function call.

In many languages, `forEach` is often called just `each`. The following discussion uses JavaScript only for reference. It could really be any other language.

Now, let's use each of these functions.

#### Using `forEach`:

**Task 1:** Write a function `printSquares`, which accepts an array of numbers `arr`, and prints the square of each element in it.

**Solution 1:**

```
var printSquares = function (arr) {
    arr.forEach(function (n) {
        console.log(n * n);
    });
};
```

#### Using `map`:

**Task 2:** Write a function `selfDot`, which accepts an array of numbers `arr`, and returns an array wherein each element is the square of the corresponding element in `arr`.

Aside: Here, in slang terms, we are trying to square the input array. Formally put, we are trying to compute it's dot product with itself.

**Solution 2:**

```
var selfDot = function (arr) {
    return arr.map(function (n) {
        return n * n;
    });
};
```

#### How is `map` a superset of `forEach`?

You can use `map` to solve both tasks, **Task 1** and **Task 2**. However, you cannot use `forEach` to solve the **Task 2**.

In **Solution 1**, if you simply replace `forEach` by `map`, the solution will still be valid. In **Solution 2** however, replacing `map` by `forEach` will break your previously working solution.

#### Implementing `forEach` in terms of `map`:

Another way of realizing `map`'s superiority is to implement `forEach` in terms of `map`. As we are good programmers, we'll won't indulge in namespace pollution. We'll call our `forEach`, just `each`.

```
Array.prototype.each = function (func) {
    this.map(func);
};
```

Now, if you don't like the `prototype` nonsense, here you go:

```
var each = function (arr, func) {
    arr.map(func); // Or map(arr, func);
};
```

#### So, umm.. Why's does `forEach` even exist?

The answer is efficiency. If you are not interested in transforming an array into another array, why should you compute the transformed array? Only to dump it? Of course not! If you don't want a transformation, you shouldn't do a transformation.

So while map can be used to solve **Task 1**, it probably shouldn't. For each is the right candidate for that.

---

#### Original answer:

While I largely agree with @madlep 's answer, I'd like to point out that `map()` is a **strict super-set** of `forEach()`.

Yes, `map()` is usually used to create a new array. However, it may **also** be used to change the current array.

Here's an example:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], b = null;
b = a.map(function (x) { a[x] = 'What!!'; return x*x; });
console.log(b); // logs [0, 1, 4, 9, 16] 
console.log(a); // logs ["What!!", "What!!", "What!!", "What!!", "What!!"]
```

In the above example, `a` was conveniently set such that `a[i] === i` for `i < a.length`. Even so, it demonstrates the power of `map()`.

[Here's the official description of `map()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19). Note that `map()` may even change the array on which it is called! Hail `map()`.

Hope this helped.

---

Edited 10-Nov-2015: Added elaboration.

Comment: -1, as this is only valid under javascript; while the question specifically talks about language agnosticy and computer science concepts, not limited implementations.

Comment: @Javier: Hmm.., I've got to agree with you about my answer being JavaScript specific.

But ask yourself this: If a language had a native `map` function but no `forEach`; couldn't you simply not use `map` instead of `forEach`?

On the flip side, if a language had `forEach` but no `map`, you'd have to implement your own `map`. You couldn't simply use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Tell me what you think.

Answer (score 11):

the most 'visible' difference is that map accumulates the result in a new collection, while foreach is done only for the execution itself.

but there are a couple of extra assumptions: since the 'purpose' of map is the new list of values, it doesn't really matters the order of execution.  in fact, some execution environments generate parallel code, or even introduce some memoizing to avoid calling for repeated values, or lazyness, to avoid calling some at all.

foreach, on the other hand, is called specifically for the side effects; therefore the order is important, and usually can't be parallelised.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example in Scala using lists: map returns list, foreach returns nothing.

```
def map(f: Int ⇒ Int): List[Int]
def foreach(f: Int ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

So map returns the list resulting from applying the function f to each list element:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> list map (x => x * 2)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Foreach just applies f to each element:

```
scala> var sum = 0
sum: Int = 0

scala> list foreach (sum += _)

scala> sum
res2: Int = 6 // res1 is empty
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Javascript in particular, the difference is that `map` is a loop function while `forEach` is an iterator.

Use `map` when you want to apply an operation to each member of the list and get the results back as a new list, without affecting the original list.

Use `forEach` when you want to *do* something on the basis of each element of the list. You might be adding things to the page, for example. Essentially, it's great for when you want "side effects".

Other differences: `forEach` returns nothing (since it is really a control flow function), and the passed-in function gets references to the index and the whole list, whereas map returns the new list and only passes in the current element.

Answer (score 0):

ForEach tries to apply a function such as writing to db etc on each element of the RDD without returning anything back.

But the `map()` applies some function over the elements of rdd and returns the rdd. So when you run the below method it won't fail at line3 but while collecting the rdd after applying foreach it will fail and throw an error which says

> File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'collect'

```
nums = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
num2 = nums.map(lambda x: x+2)
print ("num2",num2.collect())
num3 = nums.foreach(lambda x : x*x)
print ("num3",num3.collect())
```