# Java 8 forEach use cases

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

Let's say you have a collection with some strings and you want to return the first two characters of each string (or some other manipulation...).

In Java 8 for this case you can use either the `map` or the `forEach` methods on the stream() which you get from the collection (maybe something else but that is not important right now).

Personally I would use the `map` primarily because I associate `forEach` with mutating the collection and I want to avoid this. I also created a really small test regarding the performance but could not see any improvements when using `forEach` (I perfectly understand that small tests cannot give reliable results but still).

So what are the use-cases where one should choose `forEach`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354909/is-there-a-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: IMO, the advantage comes into account when the operations can be performed in parallel.

Comment: @akhil_mittal, both `map` and `forEach` can be performed in parallel.

Comment: @aioobe thank you, I did not find that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` is the better choice for this, because you're not trying to *do* anything with the strings yet, just map them to different strings.

`forEach` is designed to be the "final operation." As such, it doesn't return anything, and is all about mutating *some* state -- though not necessarily that of the original collection. For instance, you might use it to write elements to a file, having used other constructs (including `map`) to get those elements.

Answer (score 3):

[`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) terminates the stream and is exectued because of the side effect of the called [`Cosumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). It does not necessarily mutate the stream members.

[`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) maps each stream element to a different value/object using a provided [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). A `Stream <R>` is returned on which more steps can act.

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` terminal operation might be useful in several cases: when you want to collect into some older class for which you don't have a proper collector or when you don't want to collect at all, but send you data somewhere outside (write into the database, print into `OutputStream`, etc.). There are many cases when the best way is to use both `map` (as intermediate operation) and `forEach` (as terminal operation).