# Replace an element of an object by one of its own sub-elements

Tags: javascript, dictionary, enumeration

Let's say I have:

```
let list = [{a: {b: 'foo'}}, {a: {b: 'bar'}}]
```

I want to end up with:

```
list = [{a: 'foo'}, {a: 'bar'}]
```

This works:

```
list = list.map(d => {d.a = d.a.b; return d})
```

But I have a bad feeling that changing the value in place is a bad idea.

Is there a cleaner way? is my solution actually valid?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your solution

Comment: use forEach instead of map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and change the object in situ, because you need not to return a new array, while you already mutate the original object of the array.

```js
let list = [{ a: { b: 'foo' } }, { a: { b: 'bar' } }];

list.forEach(d => d.a = d.a.b);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Would this be better? why?

Comment: @MasterScrat, have a look here for a short comparison https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354909/is-there-a-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Answer (score 1):

It is not changing the value in place.

`map` method only creates a new array by applying a `callback` provided function for every item in the array.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

For changing the value in place you can use `forEach` method.