# JS foreach loop to update an array element

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript.
And I tried to use a foreach loop to update my elements in an array.
But the problem is that the "console.log" result always been the same array as before.
Below is the code. 
Can anyone help tell the problem?

```
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

var addNum = function(element,index,array){
    if(element%3===0)
    {
        element += 100;
    }
};

test.forEach(addNum);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 8):

That's because in JavaScript arguments are passed by value, not by reference.
So changing `element` argument does nothing.

In your case, it is better to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```
var addNum = function(element,index,array){
    if(element%3===0)
    {
        return element + 100;
    }

    return element
};

const result = test.map(addNum);
console.log(result);
```

If you really need to use `forEach` - you could do it like this:

```
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

var addNum = function(element,index,array){
    if(element%3===0)
    {
        array[index] += 100;
    }
};

test.forEach(addNum);
console.log(test);
```

But this is, in my opinion, a bad practice.
`forEach` is designed for doing something with each element in an array without changing it, but `map` is specifically designed to create new array running a function on each element of the provided array.
Also see discussion here [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354909/is-there-a-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Comment: Yeah maybe the one who answer was deleted a second ago

Comment: The shorter version I could successfully run on FireFox 57 is:
const result= test.map(i=>i%3===0? i+100: i);

Comment: Why is using `forEach` a bad practice exactly? Any reference to back this up?

Comment: In forEach statement you have to change the state of a variable outside of the function, but map just creates a new copy of the array which has no side effect.  if you run forEach multiple times, you'll get different answers

Comment: Changing the value of the original array is not a side-effect, but the actual purpose of using `forEach` in that context. The OP never explicitly said they wanted to modify a shallow copy of the original array, instead of the original array itself. Calling it bad practice, because of that is at least misinformation.

Comment: Judging by the context of the question and the code - using `forEach` here is a bad practice.

Comment: In your opinion; that's the point I'm trying to make. It's not like the programming world, in general, considers the use of `forEach` bad practice. You have to be careful with your wording when addressing someone new to the language. Besides, _`update my elements in an array`_ sounds to me like the OP wants to modify the original array.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer, added: "in my opinion". But please note that everything I'm writing is only my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

In your `addNum` function, `element` is just an argument. When you modify it , you are only modifying the value inside the function, not the actual element in the array.

To modify the array, you need to target the element:

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

var addNum = function(element, index, array) {
    if (element % 3 === 0) {
        array[index] = element + 100;
    }
};
test.forEach(addNum);
console.log(test);
```

Note that in JavaScript you can directly pass an anonymous function to `forEach()`:

```
test.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if (element % 3 === 0) {
        array[index] = element + 100;
    }
});
```