# What is the Difference between mapPartitions and foreachPartition in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame and in that one column is has comma separated data.

For Example : Data looks like this :
[{value:1}, {value:2, value:3}, {some value}, {somevalue, othervalue}]

The column is of String datatype. I want to convert it to List and apply some function.
Now i have a function for doing the conversion of the String column to List & other applied logic.

But which function will be better & optimized as we have 2 similar sounding functions **mapPartitions** & **foreachPartitions**, Does it have exact same performance & in which one to use in what scenario ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354909/is-there-a-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Answer (score 5):

The difference is the same as that between map and foreach. Look here for good explanations - [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354909/is-there-a-difference-between-foreach-and-map).

mapPartitions and foreachPartitions are transformations/operations that apply to each *partition* of the Dataframe as opposed to each *element*. See here for an explanation contrasting map and mapPartitions - [Apache Spark: map vs mapPartitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions).

From your description, it sounds you want either map or foreach.