# How to return numbers from foreach in the intervals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How to return numbers from foreach function in intervals?

I must to return from my `foreach` function number in intervals, so for example i need to return `3,7,11,15,19,23,27,31 etc.`

```
data.foreach(async (e, index) => {
    await this.getNumberInIntervals(e.id, index+4); // in this parameter I must be provide a numbers with interval by 4
})
```

can someone tell me how can i do it?

this is a diffrent question than this: [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354909/is-there-a-difference-between-foreach-and-map)

Comment: How does look `data`  array? Please provide exact input and expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.foreach(async (e, index) => {
    await this.getNumberInIntervals(index * 4 + 3);
})
```